# VBA Static Class "WithEvents"?

Tags: vba, events, static

Disclaimer - I am by no means a VBA expert; I am a hack.

However, I've got some class modules that are static (using `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True`
)

I'd like to define some custom events with them, too (`Public Event Foo(ByVal Bar As Boolean`); however, since I am not instantiating the class, I'm not finding any info on any "Attributes" that will include "WithEvents" when "PreDeclaredID" is true.

Yes, I can use the class without its being static; however, I'd prefer to find a way for it to be declared automatically *WithEvents*, if it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because there is no reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class has static *semantics*, but it's not static in the `static` sense you're referring to.

The `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True` means the compiler generates a global (or project-scoped, if the class is private) instance that is named after the class module itself.

In other words, there is *literally* an object/instance named `Class1` (assuming the class module is named `Class1`), exposing the default interface defined by the `Class1` module (i.e. it's an object whose compile-time type is `Class1` regardless of what other interfaces that class might be implementing).

So *you* are not instantiating it, but the VBA compiler does.

And that object behaves every single bit the same as any other object you might have - there is no reason a `Public Event` could not be declared in it, and you can `Set` a `WithEvents` object variable to that "free" global instance, which you can refer to by name from anywhere in the project:

```vb
Private WithEvents Thing As Class1 '<~ requires Public Event declaration in Class1.

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Thing = Class1 '<~ will not compile unless Class1 has VB_PredeclaredId=True.
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add, `WithEvents` objects cannot be declared in a Standard module.

Comment: Ah. I see now. I had been using the class' methods and properties without declaring anywhere another object as that class. Once I declared an object in another module ("WithEvents", of course), the custom event became available in that module.